Unable to Select Simulator as Tool in MPLAB X After Choosing Device
I’m working on a project in MPLAB X, and after opening the project and selecting a device (e.g., a PIC microcontroller), I’m unable to choose the simulator as the tool. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
I’ve ensured that I’ve selected a supported microcontroller for the project.
I’ve tried restarting MPLAB X and reloading the project, but the simulator option is still grayed out or unavailable.
Could anyone explain why the simulator tool isn't appearing as an option in my project setup? Is there something specific I need to do to enable the simulator in MPLAB X?
Any help would be appreciated
